# google sheet query skip columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently using the following function to import data from one spreadsheet to another and would require skip some column at destination were I can manually input the values.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com","Sheet1!A:T"),"Select Col1,Col16,Col17," ",Col2," ",Col3,Col19," ",Col14," "," "," ",Col15," ",Col17," "," ",Col19," "," ",Col11," ",Col13 where Col2 matches 'alfa.*|beeta.*' ")`

The column which I need to skip have been indicated with " ", Can someone please assist how I can do this?

I tried skipping the column by using a double quotes " "

Comment: Col17 is elected twice. Is this deliberate?

Answer (score 0):

The extra columns are inserted using:

- single quotes containing one or more spaces
- no duplicates, so increase the number spaces for each extra column
- use `label` to rename the column headers.

---

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A1:T}, "Select Col1,Col16,Col17,' ',Col2,'  ',Col3,Col19,'   ',Col14,'    ','     ','      ',Col15,'       ',Col6,'        ','         ',Col20,'          ','           ',Col11,'            ',Col13 where Col1 is not null and Col2 matches 'alfa.*|beeta.*'",1)`